# Why mongoose $pull does not remove item from an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    products: []
});
```

eg. User:

```
{ name: 'Steve', products: ['111a', '222b']}
```

I want to remove the product of given name from the user of given ID.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $pull: { products: req.body.prodId } }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) { res.send('error_3853852'); return; }
        res.send('updated'); return;
    })
```

As a result it is not removed and no error occured

Comment: "and any error occured" does this mean there was an error? if so what error

Comment: Sorry my mistake, no errors